# Pass an array to a function in Swift throwing invalid parameter type error

Tags: arrays, swift, parameters

pretty basic question here but it has me stuffed...

I'm trying to call a function (defined in another class) using this method:

```
 var idarray = Profile.getIDArray(Globals.friendlist);
```

where Globals.friendlist is an array of Profiles (i.e. [Profile?] )

Now here is my function for .getIDArray

```
func getIDArray(inputarray:[Profile?]) -> [String] {
  //Blah - code that returns an array of Strings
}
```

Whenever I try to compile this I keep getting the following error:

```
Cannot invoke 'getIDArray' with an argument list of type '([Profile?])'
```

Now here is where I'm confused - because I'm pretty certain that my function **is** accepting [Profile?] as the parameter type!

What's going wrong - is there something introduced in swift that I am unaware of?

Comment: Post your `Globals.friendList` code please

Comment: Friendlist is defined as `var friendlist:[Profile?];` and declared as a Global like `var demofriendlist = [Profile?]();` where `var Globals = Main(currentprofile: demoprofile , friendlist: demofriendlist , currentgroup: demogroup);` - I can post the entire class if you'd like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are invoking getIDArray as a type method. Probably you are missing a `class` or `static` keyword in the func declaration:

```
class func getIDArray(...  // if Profile is a class

static func getIDArray(... // if Profile is struct or enum
```

Comment: I agree, or you need to create an instance of `Profile`

Comment: This worked!! Can you please explain why you need to add a `class` before the `func` even though the function is in the Profile class block? Thanks!

Comment: func getIDArray ... is an instance method, associated with an instance of Profile; e.g. let p = Profile(...); let v = p. getIDArray ...
class func getIDArray is a type method, associated with the type itself

Comment: The `class` and `struct` keywords mean that the function belongs to the type, and not the instances of the type, meaning you reference it by using the _type name_, in this case `Profile`, instead of the specific variables of that type, declared with `var' or `let`. It applies to properties and methods as described in the docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID264
The distinction isn't specific to Swift, but the syntax may be different than what you're used to.